# Delphi DllMain DLL_PROCESS_DETACH called before DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH

Tags: windows, delphi, dll

I'm having a lot of trouble dealing with a DLL I've written in Delphi. I've set up a DllMain function using the following code in the library:

```
begin
  DllProc := DllMain;
end.
```

My `DllMain` procedure looks like this:

```
procedure DllMain(reason: Integer);
begin
  if reason = DLL_PROCESS_DETACH then
    OutputDebugString('DLL PROCESS DETACH')
  else if reason = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH then
    OutputDebugString('DLL PROCESS ATTACH')
  else if reason = DLL_THREAD_ATTACH then
    OutputDebugString('DLL THREAD ATTACH')
  else if reason = DLL_THREAD_DETACH then
    OutputDebugString('DLL THREAD DETACH')
  else
    OutputDebugString('DllMain');
end;
```

What I'm finding is that DETACH seems to be called (twice?!) by a caller (that I don't control) before ATTACH is ever called. Is that even possible, or am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work? My expectation would be that every ATTACH call would be met with a matching DETACH call, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

What's goin' on here?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately when `begin` is executed in your dll code, the OS has already called `DllMain` in your library. So when your `DllProc := DllMain;` statement executes it is already too late. The Delphi compiler does not allow user code to execute when the dll is attached to a process. The suggested workaround (if you can call that a workaround) is to call your own `DllMain` function yourself in a unit initalization section or in the library code:

```
begin
  DllProc := DllMain;
  DllMain(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end;
```

The [relevant documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/System.DLLProc):

> **Note**:  DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH is passed to the procedure only if the DLL's initialization code calls the procedure and specifies DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH as a parameter.

Comment: Hmm... I was hoping this would be the solution to all of my problems, but this additional knowledge (although true and answering my question) hasn't yet fixed my issues. Looks like I'll have to create another question :). Thanks for your help!

Comment: What don't you understand. It's all here right in this question. The only invocation of DllMain that occurs before your code can execute is for `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`. So you just write it the way Sertac says and it's all good.

Comment: No, this is entirely clear. I understand it and could implement it. It has revealed, though, that the answer to my larger problem (which I was hoping was related to this), is not in fact related to this problem. So the search continues!

Answer (score -1):

> What I'm finding is that DETACH seems to be called (twice?!) by a caller (that I don't control) before ATTACH is ever called.

According to "Programming Windows 5th edition" by Petzold.
`DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` gets called when the application starts and
`DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` when a new thread inside an attached application is started.
`DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` gets called when an application attached to your application quits.
`DLL_THREAD_DETACH` gets called when a thread inside an attached application quits.

Note that it is possible for `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` to be called without a corresponsing earlier `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`.
This occurs when the thread was started **prior** to the application linking to the dll.
This mainly occurs when an application manually loads the dll using `LoadLibrary` instead of statically linking at compile time.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean a thread without a process? And 'LoadLibrary' won't lead to a 'DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH'?

Comment: This doesn't seem to explain why `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` is happening multiple times.